# Objective c data doesn't load into tableView

Tags: objective-c, tableview

I'm trying to load some data from array into tableView but the only image does load. there the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    CarsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CarsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil][0];
    }

    cell.imageCar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[_arrayCars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"logo"]];
    return cell;
    cell.lblName.text = [[_arrayCars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    cell.lblHP.text = [[_arrayCars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"horse_power"];
    cell.lblPrice.text = [[_arrayCars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"price"];

}
```

what did I miss?

Comment: Please `return cell;` this code write last of cellForRowAtIndexPath  method.

Answer (score 2):

Your `return cell;` line is before you assign any of the text to their labels. Move this line to a place after you assign your text.

Answer (score 0):

Shift the code line `return cell;` from :

```
cell.imageCar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[_arrayCars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"logo"]];
return cell;
cell.lblName.text = [[_arrayCars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
```

to :

```
cell.imageCar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[_arrayCars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"logo"]];
cell.lblName.text = [[_arrayCars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
cell.lblHP.text = [[_arrayCars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"horse_power"];
cell.lblPrice.text = [[_arrayCars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"price"];
return cell;
```

It will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


CarsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CarsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil][0];
}

cell.imageCar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[_arrayCars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"logo"]];
return cell;
cell.lblName.text = [[_arrayCars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
cell.lblHP.text = [[_arrayCars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"horse_power"];
cell.lblPrice.text = [[_arrayCars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"price"];

return cell;

}
```